# Непонятная ошибка выдаваемая phpstan-ом

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Решил я подключить к своему проекту на PHP 7.4 [phpstan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan).
Анализ моего кода командой

```
./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse --paths-file=./phpstan.dist --level=max
```

приводит к ошибке

```
------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 Line    src/Entity/User.php                                                   
------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 11      Property App\Entity\User::$roles type has no value type specified in  
         iterable type array.                                                  
------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Проблемный код:

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    ...
    private array $roles = [];
    ...
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, выяснить проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Анализатор вам говорит, что не может определить тип элементов массива.

Т.к. PHP не позволяет объявлять типизированные массивы, то нужно воспользоваться объявлением подсказки

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    ...
    /**
     * @var RoleType[]
     */
    private array $roles = [];
    ...
}
```

(обратите внимание, что комментарий начинается с **трех** символов `/**`)

Вместо `RoleType` подставьте тот тип элементов, который у вас используется

Comment: А если у меня используется просто обычный array?
Попробовал использовать `/** @var array[] */` и ошибка пропала. Нормально ли так писать?

Comment: Как это обычный array? $roles у вас массив. Что является элементами этого массива?

Comment: Просто ужас, я знатно так тормознул! У меня обычные строки -- я всё понял. Большое спасибо!